# Every time when my redux state is updating my whole page is loading. Not exactly loading resources back from server but

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Every time when my redux state is updating my whole page is loading. Not exactly loading resources back from server but refreshing the components inside the page?

The following is my store code.
P.S : I am using multiple stores and combining them using combine reducers.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import { User } from "./User";
import { Restaraunt } from "./Restaraunt";
import { Dish } from "./Dishes";
import { Cart } from "./Cart";
import { createForms } from "react-redux-form";
import { InitialFeedback, RegisterUserDetails, RegisterRestarauntDetails, addDishDetails } from "./forms";


export const storeConfig = () => {
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            user: User,
            restaraunts: Restaraunt,
            dishes: Dish,
            cart: Cart,
            ...createForms({ feedback: InitialFeedback }),
            ...createForms({ registeruser: RegisterUserDetails }),
            ...createForms({ registerres: RegisterRestarauntDetails }),
            ...createForms({ addDish: addDishDetails })
        }),
        applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
    );
    return store;
};
```

I So I am using the cart that I mentioned a particular page. So when ever my cart is updating then my whole page is loading again.

Comment: It depends how you connect your components and if reducers are creating new state even if they don't need to. Are you using connect or useSelector and are you using reselect with that?

Answer (score 1):

This a bit too broad to be honest.

You should take a look at every component in your react app and make sure that they only re-render when needed.
Things you can do:

1. You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle if you have class-based components that should update only when few of the props change.
2. You can use `React.memo` to memoize a component and prevent unnecessary rerender.
3. `useCallback` hook on functions for memorizing them.

Comment: Also a `useSelector(state=>({new:'object'}))` will cause that component to re render every time a dispatched action causes any change to the state.

Comment: Yeah, that one too. There's no one answer for OP's question.